# how can define timer count in java android studio

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I want to define a time counter from 0 to 30 seconds in the onClick listener of a Button.
When the Button is clicked, the time counter starts and it has an if condition to check, for example, if timecounter=10. Then my ImageView becomes visible

This is my trial:

```
base.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                if(millisUntilFinished==5000)
                {
                    base.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();


    }
});
```

I want that when I click the Button, after 5 seconds my image view becomes visible.
If anyone can help, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to this code hope this can help..

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000).equalsIgnoreCase("10")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 second remaining.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                base.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: with this code my purpose done but . can understand about millisUntilFinished / 1000).equalsIgnoreCase("10")) i change it to 5 and when i click 26sec reaminig to visible my pic!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use 25000 instead 5000 because  millisUntilFinished shows the milli-seconds remaining.

**Solution:**

Try this code:

```
if(millisUntilFinished >= 25000 && millisUntilFinished < 26000)
{
      base.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

OR

```
if(millisUntilFinished/1000 == 25)
{
      base.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: do that nothing happened

Comment: Try something to print on every second in logcat, and also make a log in if condition so as to check if the condition is being checked or not.

Comment: You can upvote the answer if it helped you :) @erfan